# ClassNotFoundException while running a Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to Spring boot.I am getting ClassNotFoundException :Spring Application while doing the sample example using spring 1.5.7. I googled for solution and added spring boot maven build plugin.But still the problem not resolved. Please help.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Below is my main class

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I am getting the below Exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: please provide more details like code snippet and complete stack trace in order to better understand your problem

Comment: same code working with 1.5.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to create a spring boot project from scratch irrespective of build tool (maven, gradle, etc..) is to use https://start.spring.io/ search for your dependencies like (Web, actuator, etc..) and generate the project. Unzip the downloaded project and type the respective command `mvn spring-boot:run` in your case.

Comment: I am using STS and created the project using Spring Starter Project

Comment: Did you try running `mvn spring-boot:run` from command line ? If so can you try clearing your local maven repository (windows : c:\users\<username>\.m2 mac : ~\.m2) and then run it again? See if your maven command result whether it is downloading any dependencies, or if it throws any error while downloading it.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that relevant dependencies are not downloaded from maven repo. 
Try following command and check if the package compiles okay!

```
./mvnw clean package
```